# Thinking of switching to a salt water pool

Tags: pool

I’m getting conflicting opinions from a couple local pool service providers on the benefits of going to a saltwater pool.

I’m hearing it’s maintenance free compared to regular chlorine.
Then I hear it’s not maintenance free because you have additional chemical levels to watch.

The worst part is the anti-salt folks mentioned the pool can turn green even if the chemicals are in balance. 
I have a 36k gallon pool with a heater, Hayward 2 speed pump and a big de filter.

Any advice if I should switch to salt?

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not maintenance free.  A salt water pool is still a chlorinated pool but due to the salt levels it uses less chlorine.   I have had both pool types.   To sum it up the chlorine pool does require more daily maintenance as the chlorine levels have to be high but not too high.   Everything else though is easy on a chlorine pool.

The salt water pool only needs to be checked a couple times a week and usually serviced weekly.   It has higher start up costs and you have to watch for corrosion due to the salt.   I preferred the salt water pool but it wasn't a huge difference.

(Most pool places will try to sell you a saltwater pool as it makes them more money - unless they think you will buy chlorine through them.   In my opinion salt water is probably cheaper in long run if your pool is in an open yard.  If my pool is near trees I would go chlorine as the salt water pools do not handle the extra bugs/leaves/stuff as well as the higher chlorinated pools.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You mention that a salt water pool doesn’t handle bugs and leaves etc. does it throw the chemicals out of balance? And is it harder to get saltwater pool chemical levels back on track than chlorine pools.

Comment: @Tonkadog -  A normal pool just zaps all issues with massive chlorine.   Dealing with "odditities/debris" is a bigger deal with a salt water pool.   The levels get out of whack quickly and if you are going a week without checking, yea problems can come up.    I also felt that the chlorine pool handled the beginning and the end of the season better...